# Building a online Q&A site using Grails Framework

Tags: grails

I come from a Java background using Java EE components. I know there are open source frameworks which are django based to build online question and answer sites and currently I am trying out couple. But I want to actually do this by using Grails. I was wondering if someone could point me towards right direction. I couldn't find any Grails based information on building such web application.

Comment: Are you looking for tips on Grails plugins that would implement some functionality of this Q&A site, or help on how to do web development in Grails in general or what? Developing XYZ app in Grails seems like a narrow topic since it is an all-round general web dev framework.

Comment: I'd just use OSQA http://www.osqa.net/. It's a SO clone.

Comment: @BradRhoads OSQA is written in Python, so can't be easily included in a Grails app.

Comment: If you need this as part of a larger app, you're right. I'd probably look at using the weceem plugin in that case.

Comment: @Arjan Tijms did you ever find a grails based framework for q&a? It would be great if you could share your experience incase if you built one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a traditional forum, or a Q&A website like stackoverflow.com? If you're asking about the former, I would recommend creating a Grails application or plugin that encapsulates the functionality provided by [jforum](http://jforum.net/). A plugin would be best, because then you (and possibly others) could re-use this functionality across Grails apps.

Writing your own Q&A website from scratch doesn't make a lot of sense unless your forum is significantly different to those that are already available.